# How to get keypressed event for table view

Tags: qt, qt5

This is my code of DropMimeData for the Tree Model.

The code works as expected , the user can drag and drop a treeitem from one location in the table view to another location in the view..

I need to add a condition in mimeData function based on Cntrl KeyPressed.

1) How can i get to know if the cntrl key is pressed in the function.

```
bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *mimeData, Qt::DropAction 
action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{   
if (!mimeData->hasFormat(s_treeNodeMimeType)) {
    return false;
}
QByteArray data = mimeData->data(s_treeNodeMimeType);
QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint64 senderPid;
stream >> senderPid;
if (senderPid != QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) {
    return false;
}
TreeItem *parentNode = getItem(parent);
int count;
stream >> count;

if (row == -1) {
    if (parent.isValid())
        row = 0;
    else            
        row = rowCount(parent);
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    qlonglong nodePtr;
    stream >> nodePtr;
    TreeItem *node = reinterpret_cast<TreeItem *>(nodePtr);

    if (node->row() < row  && parentNode == node->parent())
        --row;

    TreeItem *nodeNew = new TreeItem(node->GetContainer(), parentNode);
    nodeNew->setContainer(node->GetContainer());
    parentNode->insertChild(row, nodeNew);
    endInsertRows();
    ++row;
//  if( ctrl key is pressed ) while dragging and dropping item the Cntrl key is pressed
    //  removeItem(node); 
}   
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers() != Qt::ControlModifier)
     removeItem(node);
```